# How join a table and selectable stored procedure filtering some rows?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird

In Firebird 2.5.9, I am trying to join a stored procedure in a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN STORED_PROC(T1.STARTDATE) ON 1=1
WHERE T1.STARTDATE IS NOT NULL
```

This stored procedure has a parameter, a data, that it is declared as not null.

When I execute it, I get the following error:

> insert failed because a column definition includes validation
> constraints.Validation error for variable MINDATE, value "*** null
> ***".

I seems that it is receiving a null value, even the WHERE should excloude the null values. I thought that LEFT JOIN forces to evaluate first the table. Does it mean that the LEFT JOIN includes all records, do the join, and finally filter using the WHERE?

If I do:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN STORED_PROC('2021-1-1') ON 1=1
WHERE T1.STARTDATE IS NOT NULL
```

it does not return error, but obviously it is not correct. It is just to confirm that the error is in the passed date.

Finally, if I do:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE T1.STARTDATE IS NOT NULL) AS A1
LEFT JOIN STORED_PROC(A1.STARTDATE) ON 1=1
```

then it works fine, but I would like to know because the first version does not work.

Comment: `STORED_PROC('2021-1-1')` <> `STORED_PROC(T1.STARTDATE)`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just filter the values first and then can join it -

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM T1
         WHERE T1.STARTDATE IS NOT NULL) TEMP
  LEFT JOIN STORED_PROC(TEMP.STARTDATE) ON 1=1
```